# Importing symbology to specific unique value in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.3

I am working with arcview 10.3. I trying to change the symbology of unique value "43" in layer "Total" to the same symbology as in layer "a2-land".

[image]

but in the layer properties when i choose import button i can't find option to do it

[image]

and as a result the whole "Total" layer's symbology turn to the same as layer "a2". The problem is that all other unique value in layer "Total" disappear and i do want that other values: 574,431,155, will remain the same as before:

[image]

Comment: i re edit my question  now

Comment: yes they are lyr files

Comment: I'm not sure you can do anything other than drill into the properties of a2/land (More Colors...) and make a note of the RGB values, then replicate those manually in Total/43.

Answer (score 2):

That's how importing symbology works in ArcGIS.  You can import the symbology from one layer to another layer then tweak it as you wish.  If your source symbology relies on unique values in multiple fields, those same fields need to exist in the target layer or you can remap then in the import dialog.

You can save your own individual symbol in the Style Manager however. This way you can name and categorize your individual symbols, then search and load them into any layer of that same geometry type to replace an existing symbol. To save a symbol, click on the the symbol in the TOC, then Save As in the Symbol Selector where you can assign a category and name. You can then search symbols in the Symbol Selector by name/category.

Creating complex symbolgy takes time and manual effort but once you create a new your layer files, you can reuse them.

Comment: @newGIS This is pretty much it. If you import a lyr file, or the symbology directly from a layer, you get *all* of the symbology and not just one symbol. Anything that doesn't match would be set to 'all other values' depending on how the original symbology was defined. If are just wanting to transfer a single symbol but keep all the others, you have to do it manually. Either by 'recreating' the same symbol in the other layer as Andy suggests, or saving that particular symbol to a style as Jakub mentions and then selecting that style as the symbol for that value in the other layer.

Answer (score -1):

Once I had the same problem, be sure that both layers have the same extant, for example if they are raster they should have the same number of pixels. generally both layer should have the same characteristics either they are raster or feature.

Comment: Rasters don't need to have the same extent (nor does vector) or number of pixels to apply symbology. All that matters is that the values the symbology is based on are present and of the same type (both raster or both vector, as your last sentence states).

Comment: i didn't mention a raster. the issue is with 2 layers